# ArchLinux NetworkManager not asking for Wifi Passphrase

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, gnome3

I have freshly installed archlinux with Gnome3 on my Dell Inspiron 1520. I am using b43 broadcom drivers since my wifi card's pcid is `14e4:4312`.

When I installed NetworkManager(with gnome keyring) it sees all the available Wifi Connections, but whenever I click on a encrypted connection it first asks for Admin Authentication(On the very first try), then proceeds to disconnect and automatically connect to the first available non encrypted connection.

Is there something that I haven't installed and/or configured?

Here is the log

```
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: activated -> disconnected (reason 'none') [100 30 0]
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason: 0).
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost dhcpcd[7049]: received SIGTERM, stopping
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost dhcpcd[7049]: wlan0: removing interface
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 7049
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'Auto foo'
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <warn> (pid 7049) unhandled DHCP event for interface wlan0
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost kernel: [148464.208676] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'Auto foo' has security, but secrets are required.
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <warn> No agents were available for this request.
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [60 120 7]
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for access point (foo)
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> Marking connection 'Auto foo' invalid.
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed.
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason: 0).
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
Jul  4 19:18:14 localhost NetworkManager[741]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, didn't have network-manager-applet installed.

Got answer from the archlinux forum

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=122059

Answer (score 1):

When nm-applet starts, it registers itself with NetworkManager as a "secret" agent. When NetworkManager needs to ask for a password, it asks the agent to interact with the user.

However, it wasn't working on my Arch system:

```
$ pacman -Q network-manager-applet 
network-manager-applet 0.9.8.0-1
```

I compiled nm-applet from Git (nma-0-9-8 branch, commit 742e5daf91) and that worked.